# Call QT C++ function from Angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, c++, angularjs, qt

I currently have a QWebView which displays a hello message. Is there any way to call a C++ function from an angular controller? I want the user to be able to click on a button to invoke the C++ function in my QT project. Let's say the button has a ng-click="invokableMethod()" attribute. Then in the controller:

```
$scope.invokableMethod() 
{
    // call C++ function from here
}
```

I have been using this (http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/tutorial-74-calling-function-from-javascript-using-qtwebkit-bridge/) way previously with Javascript, but this time the website is using angular.js and I am clueless on how to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is calling function from Angluar different from calling it from plain JavaScript?